# Adding new lines in a textarea with javascript (ie 9)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, textarea

Looked all over, but I can't find the answer. I am trying to generate JSON from some inputs and display the generated JSON in a textarea, like below. But no matter what I try, I can't get my fields to show on separate lines. Any help appreciated

```
  var txt = "{a : 'a',\r\nb : 'b'\r\n}";
  document.getElementById('eventsJSON').innerHTML = txt;
```

Edit: I have simplified my example to something reproducable that demonstrates my problem

Comment: What's your `findElement` function, your HTML code and your JSON content?

Comment: I [can't reproduce your issue](http://jsfiddle.net/5payauch/), though `\n` only does the trick too. Can you create a reproducable example at http://jsfiddle.net. You're not actually showing how you're setting the value of the textarea ... Or you've some CSS preventing line-breaks?

Comment: `textarea` has `value` property, use it instead of `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this replace function:

```
.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\r\n');
```

It might also be a matter of using an innerText instead of a value change:

```
... elem.innerText + (!fields.local[i].number ? "'" : '') ...
```

Comment: I have updated my question so it should be clearer what I am trying to do

Comment: Did you try using innerText as I've suggested?